Loyalty management Adjust Points no category showing
I am working with Loyalty Management, we are testing the Adjust Points action, but I cannot see any categories, I understand that there should be at least 2 categories by default but none are visible. I have all Loyalty permissions on my user. So I think maybe it's something we haven't done in the configuration. Any ideas? thank you so much.


Go to the Object 'Transaction Journal' and then find the field
'Journal Reason'. add the values to this picklist in order to have more options in the Category for Adjust Points
